# 马耳他屿, 为什么这个岛屿用了这些字？

Tags: word-requests

I have relatives in Malta. I want to know why in Chinese people in Malta are from 马耳他屿. Are they seen as (residing in an island where people would be) having ears like that of horses, perhaps due to their overall keenness on learning about languages (and culture)?

Thanks.

Comment: An alternative phonetic transcription of Malta is 馬爾他 (马尔他).

Comment: Pure ideographics can't write modern languages

Answer (score 2):

[马耳他](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A9%AC%E8%80%B3%E4%BB%96) is just a [transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) of the name [Malta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malta).

Many Chinese transliterations are just purely phonetic and the characters are simply representations of the pronunciation.